# Particle Animation Speeds

Tags: animation, particles

Is there a way to slow down a particle effect?

Here's the blend file I'm currently working on [image]

I've tried using keyframes but I don't think I'm experienced enough with them to figure out how to make them work for this purpose.

Comment: Under emission, there's several settings you can tweak the amount of particles and lifespan.

Under velocity you can slow it down.

Comment: I've tried slowing down the velocity in multiple places in the particle settings. None of them achieve the actual effect of slowing down the general effect. I may have missed a velocity setting in there, it is a possibility. I'll double check.

Comment: You've got the Normal emission set to 10. That means that particles will start with a velocity of 10 units along the surface normal of the emitter. That's quite fast. Have you tried reducing that? What effect are you trying to achieve?